# How to get value from map object in dart

Tags: dart

I have a Map object

```
Map decodedresp = json.decode(response);
```

from here i get a list :

```
print(decodedresp['objectUrls']);

[{signedUrl: abc.com, path: a/b/c.log}]
```

now I want to get abc.com in a string, and I am not able to get it

I am learning dart and I am new to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, from what I can see it looks like you're dealing with parsed json.

In decoding json like you did `json.decode(response)` you're getting a:

`_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>`

From that you are accessing `objectUrls` which returns a `List<Map>`. In order to deal with that you need to look for the key which in this case is `signedUrl` or `path`. Because your Map is wrapped in a List you need to get the element of the List.

This should work for you

```
Map<String, dynamic> decodresp = json.decode(response);
List<dynamic> objectUrls = decoderesp['objectUrls'];
// Zero here to get the first element, followed by the key.
var signedUrl = objectUrls[0]["signedUrl"];
var path = objectUrls[0]["path"];
```

[You can see it working here](https://dartpad.dev/4bb13758d76d0bda508237dc88620ba2)

I could be wrong but because there isn't much info this is what I'm going with. 
Let me know if you have any problems.

Felix.